# Unable to figure out the difference between Pandas .mask() and .where methods

Tags: python, pandas

What is the difference between .where and .mask? I looked at the syntax and parameters, they look very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This methods are similar, bit working inverse.

[`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) - replace values where the condition is True.

[`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) - Replace values where the condition is False.

Check sample data, for `mask` data with same condition are replaced values matched `True`, here greater like `4`, for `where` method are replaced data matched `False`, here NOT greater like `4`, so less or equal:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
})

print(df.A > 4)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

df['new1'] = df.A.mask(df.A > 4, 100)
df['new2'] = df.A.where(df.A > 4, 100)
print(df)
   A  new1  new2
0  7   100     7
1  8   100     8
2  9   100     9
3  4     4   100
4  2     2   100
5  3     3   100
```